# PubNub channelGroup.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, pubnub

I'm working with PubNub for a secure messaging system and I'm running into problems with the channel listing returning a 'not a function error'. Here is my code for this:

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "#vendorMessages", function(event, ui) {
    var channelGroup = String(window.vendorID);
    pubnub.subscribe({
        channelGroups: channelGroup
    })
    pubnub.channelGroups.listChannels({
            channelGroup: channelGroup
        }, 
        function (status, response) {
            console.log("listing push channel for device")
            response.channels.forEach( function (channel) {
                console.log(channel)
            })
            response.channels.forEach( function (channel) {
                var channelFormatted = String(channel).split("_");
                var channelMember = channelFormatted[1];
                var e = $("#channelResults");
                e.append("<li onClick='loadChannel("+channel+")>"+channelFormatted+"</li>");
                e.listview("refresh");
            })
        }
    )
})
```

It is returning this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: channelGroups.forEach is not a function
    at _class.adaptSubscribeChange (https://cdn.pubnub.com/sdk/javascript/pubnub.4.4.4.js:3392:22)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (http://www.weddingindustryinsider.com/www/index.html:504:10)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js:4641:9)
    at HTMLDocument.elemData.handle (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js:4309:28)
    at Object.trigger (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js:4550:12)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js:5260:17)
    at Function.each (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js:383:23)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js:136:17)
    at jQuery.fn.init.trigger (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js:5259:15)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._triggerWithDeprecated (https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:5020:29)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem.
The problem is that channels, or channelGroups parameters should be an array.

Replace:

```
var channelGroup = String(window.vendorID);
```

By:

```
var channelGroup = [String(window.vendorID)];
```